# Questions about some properties of random probabilities and random expectations

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space with $\mathcal{A}$ countably generated, and let $P: \mathcal{A} \times \Omega \to [0,1]$ be a random probability measure. By that I mean $P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ in its first argument and an a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function in its second argument.

Assume that for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$
$$\mathbb P(A) = \int P(A,\omega)\mathbb P(d\omega), \tag{1}$$
and that for $\mathbb P$ almost every $\omega$ and all $A \in \mathcal{A}$
$$P(A, \omega) = \int P(A, \omega')P(d\omega', \omega).\tag{2}$$

For each $\omega \in \Omega$, let $C_\omega = \{\omega' \in \Omega: P(\cdot, \omega') = P(\cdot, \omega)\}$.

> Do (1) and (2) imply that for $\mathbb{P}$ almost every $\omega$
>   $$P(C_\omega, \omega)=1? \tag{3}$$
>   Does (2) imply (3) without (1)? Can the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is countably generated be dropped?

It's easy to see that $(3)$ implies (2), and [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Haim_Gaifman/publication/221551242_A_Theory_of_Higher_Order_Probabilities/links/55be62c208ae9289a099d712.pdf) (Theorem 2) asserts that the answer to my first question is affirmative, by "advanced ergodic theory." I have been unable to reconstruct the argument that (1) and (2) imply (3), with ergodic theory or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially Theorem 7 of

> Blackwell, David. "[Idempotent Markoff chains](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968811)." Annals of Mathematics
>   (1942): 560-567.

Blackwell shows there that if $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ is countably generated and (2) holds
for all $\omega$ and $A$, then (3) holds for all $\omega$ outside a measurable set $N$ such that $P(N,\omega)=0$ for all $\omega$. This clearly implies the desired result since (1) implies then that $\mathbb{P}(N)=0$ and we can always get rid of a null set on which (2) fails to apply Blackwell's result to the resulting smaller space.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really nice paper. I must say I find Blackwell's elementary proof a lot more elegant than the ergodic theory approach. Do you happen to know if this result is from Blackwell's PhD thesis? I suspect it might be just based on the timeline and the thesis title, but I don't have a copy of the thesis.

Comment: The answer is yes. There is a very long interview with Blackwell available [here](https://sites.tufts.edu/histmath/files/2015/11/blackwell.pdf). Blackwell discusses the content of his thesis on page 27 (of the PDF).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems easier to me to reformulate the question in Markov terms. Then your "random probability measures" become just the transition probabilities of a Markov chain on $\Omega$, condition (1) means that the measure $\mathbb P$ is stationary, and condition (2) means that almost surely one step transition probabilities coincide with the two step transition probabilities. Assuming the measure $\mathbb P$ is ergodic, this implies (by the ergodic theorem), that almost all transition probabilities coincide with $\mathbb P$. In the general case one decomposes $\mathbb P$ into the ergodic components with respect to the chain (this is where one needs the separability condition) and applies the above argument component-wise.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following this. By "almost all transition probabilities coincide with $\mathbb P$" do you mean $P(\cdot, \omega) = \mathbb P$ a.e. $\omega$?

Comment: Yes - precisely

Comment: Ah I see, I was forgetting that $\mathbb P$ is assumed to be ergodic in that statement. I still don't see how the last step works though. How does the ergodic decomposition lead to (3)?

Comment: On each ergodic component the transition probabilities are constant and coincide with the conditional measure of $\mathbb P$ on this component